# Show Mobiscroll popup on mobile device across entire viewport on non-mobile optimized site?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, viewport, mobiscroll

This may be a dumb question as I am currently learning about making sites mobile friendly.

I am currently working with an mvc 4 website/webapp that is not optimized for mobile.  It uses an image background that defines the "workspace" of the web app.  That image is a lot larger than mobile viewports etc.  So more work needs to go into making a complete mobile site.  However, the owner wanted to use the Mobiscroll plugin.  When the site is viewed on a mobile device, the mobiscroll popup/modal is very small and does not look like the demos since the entire site is not optimized for mobile.

Is it possible to set only the mobiscroll popup to scale to mobile and not the rest of the site?  Basically the site would still be a desktop version but the mobiscroll popup would scale up to the screen size?

Answer (score 0):

In order to show mobiscroll in "normal" size, use this meta tag in your html's head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

Comment: I understand that.  The issue I described is that this particular site uses a background picture for the work area that is larger than the width=device-width with a scale of 1.  So user-scalable=0 can't be used.  When the user scales, the mobiscroll wheels are very small.  I was just looking for a quick way to have those wheels scale up to the "device-width" so to speak.